# Avoid iOS Permission Dialog When Modifying Photo

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, photokit, ios-permissions

I am trying to prevent iOS from showing the following dialog when pictures taken with the app are edited by the user:

[image: iOS Allow App To Modify Photo Dialog]

According to Apple's documentation for PHContentEditingOutput:

> If your app edits the contents of assets already in the Photos
>   library—including assets your app has itself recently added—Photos
>   prompts the user for permission to change the asset’s content. If
>   instead your app uses the initWithPlaceholderForCreatedAsset: method
>   to create an asset with edited content, Photos recognizes your app’s
>   ownership of the content and therefore **does not need to prompt the
>   user for permission** to edit it.

However, I seem to always get the permission dialog. This is code for adding the picture to the photo library:

```
var assetPlaceholder:PHObjectPlaceholder!  

PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({  
    let creationRequest = PHAssetCreationRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImageAtFileURL(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: originalImagePath))  
    assetPlaceholder = creationRequest!.placeholderForCreatedAsset  

    let editingOutput = PHContentEditingOutput(placeholderForCreatedAsset: assetPlaceholder!)  
    editingOutput.adjustmentData = adjustmentData  
    imageData.writeToURL(editingOutput.renderedContentURL, atomically: true)  

    creationRequest!.contentEditingOutput = editingOutput  
}, completionHandler: { (success:Bool, error: NSError?) in  
    handler(assetPlaceholder.localIdentifier, error)  
})
```

To edit the picture I use:

```
let inputOptions = PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions()  
inputOptions.networkAccessAllowed = true  
inputOptions.canHandleAdjustmentData = { adjustmentData in  
    return adjustmentData.formatIdentifier == thisAppFormatIdentifier  
}  

asset.requestContentEditingInputWithOptions(inputOptions, completionHandler: { ( editingInput, info) -> Void in  
    let editingOutput = PHContentEditingOutput(contentEditingInput: editingInput!)  

    PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({  
        let changeRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest(forAsset: asset)  
        editingOutput.adjustmentData = adjustmentData  
        imageData.writeToURL(editingOutput.renderedContentURL, atomically: true)  
        changeRequest.contentEditingOutput = editingOutput  
    }, completionHandler: { (success:Bool, error: NSError?) in  
        handler(error)  
    })  
})
```

This last part always triggers the system dialog. What can I do to prevent the alert from showing?

Comment: I don't see you calling `initWithPlaceholderForCreatedAsset` anywhere ...

Comment: @JohnHascall that is an Objective-C call. In Swift this line should be equivalent: ```let editingOutput = PHContentEditingOutput(placeholderForCreatedAsset: assetPlaceholder!)```

Comment: Any solution found yet?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not found one yet. I guess we need to request Apple to soften its policy in regards to this.